# Guidance with writing Prolog rule

Tags: prolog, rule

I am in my initial phase of writing code in Prolog and am still trying wrap my head around the paradigm so please pardon the primitiveness of this question.

I read in Wikipedia

```
A rule is of the form
Head :- Body.
and is read as "Head is true if Body is true".
```

That's simple enough. So I am building a knowledge base that simulates the functioning of a 1-bit adder.

In doing so, I am trying to create a rule for the following:

> If there exists a gate X, and X is an AND gate, and X
>   has a terminal going out of it, and that terminal has a signal and the
>   signal is 0 THEN gate X must also have at least one input terminal
>   that has a signal of 0.

As a Prolog rule, I wrote this to reflect my above sentence:

`gate(X) /\ gate_type(X, and) /\ terminal(T, X, out) /\ signal(T, SIG) /\ (SIG is 0) :- (gate(X) /\ gate_type(X, and) /\ terminal_type(R, X, in) /\ signal(R, 0)).`

To test my rule, I had a terminal `t7` that is a terminal of an AND gate.

```
terminal_type(t7, a1, in).
gate_type(a1, and).
```

When I ask Prolog: `signal(t7, 1), signal(t8, 1), signal(t9, X).` or anything like that, Mr. Prolog tells me

```
X = 1;
X = 0;
```

The answer I get should be only X = 1.

Comment: I think that you might need to rewrite your rule as a Horn clause: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horn_clause

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to Prolog programming! It's very cool that you're coming at it from the hardware, almost as far from this as you can get.

I think I see two problems.

The first one is that your definition leaves out the defining characteristic of the AND gate, which is that when both inputs are 1 the output will be 1. Your translation into Prolog is a little odd-looking but certainly should take this into account. So I think in Prolog what you're trying to say is this:

```
signal(R, 0) :- 
  gate(X), gate_type(X, and), 
  terminal_type(R, X, out),
  terminal_type(R1, X, in), signal(R1, 0).
```

This isn't the whole story though. You'll need this too:

```
signal(R, 1) :- 
  gate(X), gate_type(X, and), 
  terminal_type(R, X, out),
  terminal_type(R1, X, in), terminal_type(R2, X, in), R1 \= R2,
  signal(R1, 1), signal(R2, 1).
```

This might be correct, but the second problem is that `signal(t7, 1)` is not an assertion, so it doesn't wind up in your fact database. It's just a bald structure, so it doesn't add anything to your query. The simplest solution would be to just add it to your database directly:

```
signal(t7, 1).
signal(t8, 1).
```

Then do your query:

```
signal(t9, X).
```

Or, you could `assertz/1` it:

```
assertz(signal(t7, 1)), assertz(signal(t8, 1)), signal(t9, X).
```

But that's kind of sloppy, because `assert` is a side-effect that isn't undone on backtracking.

In practice, most of the time you either make something part of the dynamic query by passing it along, or you make it part of the fact database. Mixing the two gets hard to reason about.

If I were you, I would probably simplify things by reducing the number of different fact "types" to something more like this:

```
% gate(Name, Type, Input1, Input2, Output)
gate(a1, and, t7, t8, t9).
```

Then you could really simplify the predicates by quite a bit:

```
signal(Out, 0) :-
  gate(_, and, R1, R2, Out),
  ( signal(R1, 0) ; signal(R2, 0)).
signal(Out, 1) :-
  gate(_, and, R1, R2, Out),
  signal(R1, 1),
  signal(R2, 1).
```

Comment: This is great. You've given me a few things to ponder about. I am going to try this shortly and rest assured I'll have some more feedback :p . Thanks again!

Comment: Sure thing. :) Feel free to drop me an email (check my profile) if you have questions that aren't a good fit for the S.O. format.

Comment: Appreciate it. Quick note: Is `/=` a valid operator? Compiler says "Operator expected". Should that be `\==`?

Comment: And what if `signal(Out,1)` is obtainable more than one time so for instance an AND gate with two positive inputs or an OR gate with any one input that is positive?

Comment: Are you referring to the last version I showed? In that case you're saved from the possibility by the signals being defined by position in `gate/5`. If you're referring to the code at the top, you could get multiple zeros, but they would each be "correct"—you wouldn't get a 1 when you should get 0 or vice versa. If you decide that's also a problem you can make the predicate more explicit, like the true case. But in principle there's nothing wrong with extra answers that are not incorrect, they're just wasteful.

Comment: When I convert `gate` to `gate/5` and try to run anything that has to do with `signal`, I get: `ARITHMETIC and/0 is not a function`. Any ideas?

Comment: If I am trying to create a rule for the reverse idea (given the out signal, I want to be able to decipher what comination of signals could have been input), then can I use something like this: `signal(R1, 0) :- gate(_, and, R1, R2, Out), signal(Out, 0).` . What I am trying to say is that input1 of an AND gate is 0 if the output signal is 0. Then I would create the same rule for input1 of the AND gate...

Comment: If you want to drive it other ways you'll probably want to add parameters to `signal` for the input signals. `signal/2` is doing the work, it's just not revealing it. But you may want a new predicate so that you can keep the gate logic separate from the wire logic.